# C# Удаление сертификата из хранилища

Tags: c#, windows, ssl

Пытаюсь выполнить удаление сертификата по отпечатку:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false).Cast<X509Certificate2>().First();
store.Remove(cert);
store.Close();
```

Исключений не возникает, однако сертификат продолжает отображаться в certmgr даже после перезагрузки. Интересно, что метод `Find` после удаления больше не находит ни одно сертификата с указанным отпечатком. Так же при попытке привязать удалённый сертификат к порту netsh возвращает ошибку 1312. Создаётся впечатление, что сертификат действительно был удалён, но не полностью. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Больше похоже на кеширование, чем на неполное удаление.

Comment: Как проверить средствами ОС, что сертификат точно существует?

Comment: Есть информация о [схожих проблемах](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/353654/issue-with-windows-certificate-store-still-showing). Попробую запустить на другом компьютере.